# Allow audio uploads

Tags: feature-request

I recently got stuck trying to discern whether a person in a video<sup>1</sup> was saying 湯, 言う, or something else. I figured things out eventually, but it made me think about how I would ask about these situations on JL&U.

My suggestion: **Allow audio clips to be uploaded from within the Stack Exchange post editor, just like images.**

### Pros

- Posts could include *exact* pronunciations, without relying on "it-sounded-like" descriptions.
- No [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot); the uploaded audio files would remain available for future reference.
- It could also be useful for other language-related SE sites, such as [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/) or [Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/).

### Cons

- JL&U is not [Napster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napster); perhaps uploads could be limited to a maximum of, say, 10 seconds?
- HTML5 audio format support [varies by browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats), so post-upload conversion may be needed.
- The files would need to be hosted somewhere; how much disk space would they take up?

---

<sup>1. Please note that this was an *offline* video, so linking to YouTube (and hoping that the video remained available) wasn't really an option.</sup>

Comment: Related request on ELL: [Embed an audio player](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299/embed-an-audio-player)

Answer (score 1):

I just want to let your community know that the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is trying to get some attention for [a feature request on Meta to allow language sites to embed sound clips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152282/273494). If y'all are still interested in allowing audio uploads, please add your input.